# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client using a middleware in nodejs

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm getting this error

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

when I checkif an user is authenticated  with a middleware

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) res.redirect(301,'/login');
    next();
  };

  module.exports = isAuthenticated;
```

and this is the route function

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    res.render('main/index.twig');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your if condition to return. Otherwise it could be trying to call `redirect` and then `next`.

```js
if(!req.isAuthenticated()) return res.redirect(301,'/login');
```